# Small question: Name for the $x$ of function $f$ such that $f(x)=x$?

Tags: functions, terminology

**Background**

When doing maths and chemistry problems, I often came across things like
$$x-\frac{x}{2}=\frac{x}{2}$$
It might seems trivial, but I found that it is often the presence of expressions like that in the long equations that causes special cases like "The normal phase of the solvent polarity equation on retention time is  the swapped version of when you use the reverse phase equation" which does not hold for general cases

Therefore this caused me to be interested in symmetries in expressions and my first starting point is to investigate this equation for any function f

$$f(x)=x$$

I am aware the following is called involution

$$f(f(x))=x$$

and the following is identity if it holds for all x

$$Id(x)=x$$

and x is called a root of the function if it satisfy

$$f(x)=0$$

> But if I am interested in finding some special values x in the function f such that
>
> $$f(x)=x$$
>
> What is the term for these values x
>
> Is there a generalisation to these special values x?

Comment: A point $x$ such that $f(x)=x$ is called a *fixed point of the function* $f$.

Comment: A point $x$ such that $f(x)=0$ is called a *root of the function* $f$. Such points are (probably more often) also called *zeroes of the function* (and personally I prefer this denomination).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, a point $x$ that satisfies $f(x) = x$ is called a *fixed point* of $f$. Fixed points are often of practical interest as they can guarantee that an algorithm that repeatedly uses the function $f$ will stop at some point. Therefore many fixed point theorems exist, which describe sufficient conditions for when a fixed point exists for a function. Some examples of fixed point theorems include

- [Banach fixed point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem)
- [Tarski's fixed point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Tarski_theorem)
- [Brouwer fixed point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem)